# Why does below code not find getElementsByTagName in XML in PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I'm do not understand why the below code is giving me not the values of the names. I'm already puzzling for a few hours but with no result. Any help will be very nice...

The code is:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
  $xml->LoadXml("
<node>
  <cv>
    <opleiding>
      <naam>MicrosoftOpleiding bij bill  - Microsoft</naam>
      <periode>2016</periode>
    </opleiding>
    <opleiding>
      <naam>Post Universitair Centrum (Belgie) - Master of Business Administration (Informatie, Technologie, Logistiek en Marketing)</naam>
      <periode>1987 - 1995</periode>
    </opleiding>
    <opleiding>
      <naam>Vrije Universiteit - Bedrijfskunde</naam>
      <periode>1987 - 1992</periode>
    </opleiding>
    <opleiding>
      <naam>Opleidingsinstantie - Studie HBO</naam>
      <periode>2006 - 2016</periode>
    </opleiding>
  </cv>
</node>
");
  writetolog ("Dump of XML: ". $xml->savexml());
  $nodelist = $xml->getElementsByTagName('opleiding');
  foreach ($nodeList as $node) {
    $naam = $node->getElementsByTagName('naam');
    $naamID = $naam->item(0)->nodeValue;
    writetolog ("The name in de opleiding is  " . $naamID); 
  }
  writetolog ("After the loop");
```

Then in my log file is:

```
14:26:48 Start run
14:26:48 s:644:"Dump of XML: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<node>
  <cv>
    <opleiding>
      <naam>MicrosoftOpleiding bij bill  - Microsoft</naam>
      <periode>2016</periode>
    </opleiding>
    <opleiding>
      <naam>Post Universitair Centrum (Belgie) - Master of Business Administration (Informatie, Technologie, Logistiek en Marketing)</naam>
      <periode>1987 - 1995</periode>
    </opleiding>
    <opleiding>
      <naam>Vrije Universiteit - Bedrijfskunde</naam>
      <periode>1987 - 1992</periode>
    </opleiding>
    <opleiding>
      <naam>Opleidingsinstantie - Studie HBO</naam>
      <periode>2006 - 2016</periode>
    </opleiding>
  </cv>
</node>
";
14:26:48 s:14:"After the loop";
```

Why is my $nodelist empty?

Comment: `$nodelist` != `$nodeList`

Comment: mmm, thxs did not knew that this is case sensitive... pffffff.

Comment: If i enable these errors I don't see them on my screen. I'm developing under drupal, how to get these errors to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case matters: `$nodelist` and `$nodeList` are different variables. Changing

```
$nodelist = $xml->getElementsByTagName('opleiding');
```

to

```
$nodeList = $xml->getElementsByTagName('opleiding');
```

should solve the problem.

Comment: Reference: [Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php): _The variable name is case-sensitive._

Answer (score 3):

Use below code --

```
$xml = <<< XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<node>
  <cv>
    <opleiding>
      <naam>MicrosoftOpleiding bij bill  - Microsoft</naam>
      <periode>2016</periode>
    </opleiding>
    <opleiding>
      <naam>Post Universitair Centrum (Belgie) - Master of Business Administration (Informatie, Technologie, Logistiek en Marketing)</naam>
      <periode>1987 - 1995</periode>
    </opleiding>
    <opleiding>
      <naam>Vrije Universiteit - Bedrijfskunde</naam>
      <periode>1987 - 1992</periode>
    </opleiding>
    <opleiding>
      <naam>Opleidingsinstantie - Studie HBO</naam>
      <periode>2006 - 2016</periode>
    </opleiding>
  </cv>
</node>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$opleiding = $dom->getElementsByTagName('opleiding');
foreach ($opleiding as $ople) {
    echo $ople->nodeValue;
    echo "<br/>";
}
```